Why is there a stain residue coming from my outdoor wood structures?
I purchased my first home in October of last year. According to a can we found in our basement, the previous owners had stained a set of stairs, a pergola, and a raised garden bed with Ready Seal in mahogany color.
We can tell the stain is fading a bit and want to restain, but more importantly we've noticed that a residue is coming off of these structures - it's immediately on your socks when walking on the stairs, on your shirt if you lean over the garden bed, or easily rubs off onto a paper towel. You can see from the stair picture where we had scrubbed a bit with a soap, water, and vinegar mixture. The paper towel photo is from the pergola.
Main questions here:

Did the previous owners make a mistake? Is this residue normal after  a certain amount of time, or how do I prevent this in the future? (We don't know the exact date they would have stained the structures.)
To fix this, should I just strip the previous coating following the instructions here and then apply new coats? Stripping the previous coating sounds like a pretty large job for the pergola and maybe worth calling a professional for if that is needed?







The stairs are the main annoyance. We had family over recently and the kids sat on the stairs while opening their Easter eggs. They stood up and their pants were covered in the residue. We can try scrubbing those more. The color of the residue just seems so close to the stain, it's hard to be sure. There isn't a scent or anything though. Also, the rag we used to scrub is completely stained.
